# Aurelia PhantomJs target is undefined

Tags: express, phantomjs, aurelia, prerender

We have an application runs on node , express server and aureliajs . We want to enable seo with prerendering. So we installed prerender.io and prerender-node.

But while trying to render pages with prerender , phantomjs give error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'target.__useDefault')

and the code is :

```
function ensureOriginOnExports(executed, name) {
    var target = executed;
    var key = void 0;
    var exportedValue = void 0;

    if (target.__useDefault) {
      target = target['default'];
    }
.
.
.
```

in vendor-bundle.js

ensureOriginOnExports used in two places first one :

```
DefaultLoader.prototype.loadModule = function (id) {
      var _this2 = this;

      var existing = this.moduleRegistry[id];
      if (existing !== undefined) {
        return Promise.resolve(existing);
      }

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        require([id], function (m) {
          _this2.moduleRegistry[id] = m;
          resolve(ensureOriginOnExports(m, id));
        }, reject);
      });
    };
```

second one :

```
DefaultLoader.prototype.loadModule = function (id) {
      var _this3 = this;

      return System.normalize(id).then(function (newId) {
        var existing = _this3.moduleRegistry[newId];
        if (existing !== undefined) {
          return Promise.resolve(existing);
        }

        return System.import(newId).then(function (m) {
          _this3.moduleRegistry[newId] = m;
          return ensureOriginOnExports(m, newId);
        });
      });
    };
```

Comment: Whatever is calling `ensureOriginOnExports()` isn't passing the correct property through to the `executed` var. Can you trace that back?

Comment: This issue on GitHub may be useful for you; https://github.com/miguelzakharia/aurelia-google-analytics/issues/10

Comment: It looks like the source of problem is Systemjs that loads modules of aurelia. But i dont have any idea how to change Systemjs to another module loader for aurelia.

Comment: So looks like the problem is with the aurelia-i18n plugin . When i remove it from main.ts phantomjs works normally, but when i add it to project phantomjs gives the same error. It looks like phantomjs is not supporting promises and aurelia-i18n plugin needs promises :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solition to my problem was , first i used bluebird polyfill then i had to add create intl.js polyfill under /src/intl.js .

also i had to load babel-polyfill too.

It looks like phantom js looks that file for i18n support.